# Normalised beyond MySQL knowledge?

Tags: mysql, normalization

I think I've normalised my database beyond my SQL knowledge. :) 
Here's a query I'm struggling with from my Snooker league web app. It calculates overall stats for high breaks for a team from all seasons. In the example team id 3.

```
select max(break_score) maxBreak,avg(break_score) avgBreak,
   count(break_score) breaks
from breaks
join matches on match_id=break_match
where break_player in (
select distinct player_id
from players
join team_members on player=player_id and team=3)
and (match_hometeam=3 or match_awayteam=3)
```

Tables:

- matches :

```
match_id int(11) auto_increment
match_hometeam int(11)
match_awayteam int(11)
match_date date
match_void tinyint(4)
match_status tinyint(4)
match_homescore tinyint(4)
match_awayscore tinyint(4)
match_league int(11)
```

- breaks :

```
break_id int(11) auto_increment
break_match int(11) foreign key to match_id
break_player int(11)
break_score tinyint(4)
break_clearance tinyint(4)
break_year int(11)
```

- team_members : many to many table.

```
team int(11) foreign key to teams table
player int(11) foreign key to players table
year int(11) the year that the player played for the team
```

The query above works almost as intended apart from one problem. If a player has played for more than one team then Breaks he has for all teams get included in these stats.

If the Breaks table had an extra field 'break_team' the query would be trivial. So my question is two fold, can anyone assist with the right query or should I reduce the normalisation a bit to help with these stats? When is it time to de-normalise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a readily available MySQL install, but what you're after is probably the EXISTS clause, try this and reply back if it takes care of what you need or not:

```
select max(break_score) maxBreak, avg(break_score) avgBreak, count(break_score) breaks
from breaks
join matches on match_id=break_match
where exists(select 1
from players
join team_members on player=player_id and team=3
where break_year = year
and break_player = player_id
and (match_hometeam=3 or match_awayteam=3))
```

Comment: Looks like you've fixed it. Your query collects 345 in the last column, which is the the sum of all the separate seasons totals. My query returned 347, a couple of breaks from a different season and team. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, glad it worked out for you...if you find any future glitches reply and I'll check back.